# Not Able to Attach Drag & Dragend Events to Draggable Marker (Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

can you pleas take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to attach/bind `drag` and `dragend` events to the draggable marker?

I am getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined

on

```
 marker.addListener('drag', handleEvent);
 marker.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);
```

lines

```
function initMap() {
var marker;
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});

function placeMarker(position, map) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        draggable:true,
        map: map
    });
  console.log(marker.position.lat());
}
function handleEvent(event) {
   console.log(marker.position.lat());
}
 marker.addListener('drag', handleEvent);
 marker.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the listener to the marker before it exists.  Move those definitions into the `placeMarker` function.

```
function placeMarker(position, map) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('drag', handleEvent);
  marker.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);
  console.log(marker.position.lat());
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kfn0376u/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var marker;
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });

  function placeMarker(position, map) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      draggable: true,
      map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('drag', handleEvent);
    marker.addListener('dragend', handleEvent);
    console.log(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  }

  function handleEvent(event) {
    console.log(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
  }

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```